# Local notification action wihtout touch, swift

Tags: swift, xcode, function, action, localnotification

I am looking to implement an action for a *Local Notification* without touch however am struggling to find a way to do this.

Does anyone have suggestions for a method which could be used to have an action occur without having to interact with a *Local Notification* or any ways to achieve the same effect (excluding push notifications)?

Comment: there's no way you can do that without interaction

Comment: The User interactions will be required for performing an action